# Angular2 sub templates?

Tags: angular

Is there any way to have multiple templates or sub templates for a specific component in angular2 ?

**typescript file - >**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'portal',
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
})

export class AppComponent{}
```

**main.html - >**

```
<div>
<div>bla bla bla </div>
   -- load sub html page ??????
<div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Creating a header component and passing parameter from AppComponent.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a component for this since Angular2 provides a component-based approach:

```
<div>
<div>bla bla bla </div>
   <someOtherComponent></someOtherComponent>
<div>
```

with the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'someOtherComponent',
  templateUrl: 'other.html'
})
export class SomeOtherComponent{}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported but there are plans to add support eventually. The original approach using the `@View()` decorator was dropped though (See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7363).

You can use `ngSwitch` or `ngIf` to switch between different parts of a single template.

**`>=RC.2`**

```
template: `
    <div [ngSwitch]="value">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="phone">
        phone content here
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="tablet">
        table content here
      <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        brower content here
      </div>
    </div>
`
```

**`<=RC.1`**

```
template: `
    <div [ngSwitch]="value">
      <div *ngSwitchWhen="phone">
        phone content here
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchWhen="tablet">
        table content here
      <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        brower content here
      </div>
    </div>
`
```